# Laravel 8.80.0 - Unable to output different language for month name with PHP's native setlocale() and format('F Y') in Blade view

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

So in my docker compose I have installed all the locales:

`RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales locales-all`

I see all via `locale -a` once I ssh into my rebuilt container.

Now… I have a string eg. `'1994-07-01'`. I want to output "July 1994" for English locale (en_US) and for example "Lipiec 1994" for Polish (pl_PL).

So in my blade I do `\Carbon\Carbon::parse($myStringWithDate)->format('F Y')` and before that I call `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pl_PL');` but I always get "July 1994".

What am I missing if all locales are available in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `format` method on a Carbon instance is inherited directly from PHP's DateTime class, and does not support any localisation.

To get a translated string, you can use one of two methods:

1. `formatLocalized`, which works with system locales, like the code you attempted. The big problem with this is that the locale has to be set globally, and is not *thread-safe*, meaning in some environments you can't guarantee that two different requests won't overwrite each other's settings.
2. `isoFormat`, introduced in Carbon 2, which uses a locale set on the Carbon object itself, offering much more flexibility and safety. However, beware that it uses a different set of format specifiers than PHP's native functions.

There is more information and examples in the Carbon docs at https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization

Comment: This is what I needed. Your point no. 2 `->isoFormat('MMMM YYYY')` this does the job depending on my `app()->getLocale()` which I set elsewhere in middleware. Thank you.